# Database structure advice

Tags: database, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I am building an app that has the almost the same structure of Tinder. Basically you swipe left or right and then moves on to the next person.

What is the best way to approach not showing the same user twice?

Is using a linking table the right way to go? Basically anytime they swipe right or left. It needs to make a post query to the linking table with user_id_1 for example and user_id_2.

Then the next user shows it needs to make a query to get the new user_2 and make sure its not in the linking table.